# How to get the number of elements in AutoIt array?

Tags: arrays, autoit

I have defined an array that can hold 10 elements. I have add 3 elements into it. How do I get the current number of elements of the array (which is 3 in our case)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the UBound() and LBound() functions to determine the size of the array.

Comment: can you give me an example please? i can't find the `lbound` function in the documentation.

Comment: AutoIt doesn't have LBound as arrays always start at 0. UBound will give you the size. Sometimes UBound()-1.

Answer (score 2):

UBound gives you DIMENSION of the array NOT the  current number of elements of the array!

My solution works well with string and number arrays

```
Func _UBound($a)

   local $i

   For $i=UBound($a) - 1 to 0 Step -1
      If StringLen($a[$i])>  0 Then ExitLoop
   Next
    Return $i

EndFunc
```

you can try it. _Ubound($array) gives the index of last item in the array

```
 Global $array[10]
 $array[0] = "434"
 $array[1] = "value2"
 $array[2] = 0
 $array[3] = "hjhhhkhk"
 $array[4] = 0x0000
 $array[5] = ""
 $array[6] = 01010101

MsgBox(0,Default,"Finally it is: " & _UBound($array))
```